# How to create un excutable file from a jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable

I have a java project that i did it with netbeans.My jar file works fine. I tried to convert my jar file to an excutable one with "Launch4j" software.the conversion was successfully done but when t tried to clic on the excutable file,a message show me that :a java exception has occured" what should I do and thanks for help.

Comment: The best would be to describe your problem in a Q&A forum, like SO. This would inlude **at least** the exception message, but better yet the full stack trace you get.

Comment: use this link for your problem...
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

Answer (score -1):

if your working with spring boot just add spring-boot-maven-pluggin in pom.xml and excute maven goal like maven clean install then check one fat/excutable/uber.jar will created under the target folder in spring boot project structure
and run this jar with java -jar .jar on your command prompt

Comment: You're answering the question by assuming things not explicitly stated in the content. OP doesn't mention Spring Boot (or even Spring) in the question!